# Software Design - Three-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

Layer 3 - Interface

Layer 2 - Business logic (get input from user, check if valid, send to database function)

Layer 1 - Database (creates, updates, gets records etc)

---

A user can add many contact phone numbers, if it is the first phone number added the system will automatically set that phone number to primary, and there after the user can change his primary phone number on his own.

When the first phone number record is created in the database, which layer is responsible to check if the phone number needs to be set to primary or not?

Comment: Its very simple and as the Business logic (get input from user, check if valid, send to database function) meant for it so I think,Your business logic should handle it when the phone number gets added to the user. Because the database is only for storing data, the interface just to interact with the user and the business layer to make the decisions only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Business layer. The database should be storing data, not making decisions. The interface just interacts with the user. The business layer makes the rules.

Answer (score 3):

Your business logic should handle it when the phone number gets added to the user.  You can verify it works by providing unit/integration tests for it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends what you're aiming for. As it is your business layer should handle phone being validated/set as primary. Database would still need to store that information in some way I think.

However in certain cases like security verification you'll need to do some checks at Interface, Logic and Database level. Yes it is redundant but I think you'll want to guarantee that hackers that break your interface or logic, can't go around messing with your underlying data.

Comment: The best solution is to have all business rules defined once and use some code generation tool for UI and Database layers.

Answer (score 1):

The data layer in an N-tier application isn't really supposed to do anything other than to put values in and get values in. Think of it as an persistence service.

Everything else goes into what's known as the business and/or logic layer except for UI code (you're supposed to keep those things separate in following something like MVP, MVC or MVVM).

Though this simple problem actually raises a issue with transactions, your data model should eventually prevent this, but if you cannot complete the operation as an atomic unit there always the chance that two phone numbers are put at the same time and they both end up as primary (depending on the latency between the application and database). To gracefully handling these situations you need at least think about error recovery (error handling) that propagates these problems in a meaningful manner. Don't just crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above answers, you might want to consider persisting input regardless of validity. Can add a bit more development (especially if you need to clean the data) but it can be worth it depending on your application